# Change dynamic text position in Flash via AS

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a *.fla that gets its data from a xml file with some nodes.

What I really want to know is how can I change my text x and y positions via AS?

Thanks!!

Comment: "change my text x and y" - how is this text displayed? using which control?

Comment: I have a dynamic text and depending on which xml node I'm in, I want to change this text "y" position

Comment: AS2? AS3? which flash version? Where is this dynamic text control located (which parent?)? have you assigned any instance name to this dynamic text control? where are you writing your AS3 code... more information please. Your question provides too few details.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have a for loop go through your nodes and get the data from xml, that is probably where you create your text ( TextField, Label, etc. )

if you're using a regular for loop you can change the positions there.

```
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < xmlNodes.length ; i++){
   var textField:TextField() = new TextField();
   addChild(textField);
   textField.y = textField.height * i;
}
```

if you're using a for each loop set a counter before the loop and increment it inside

```
var textFields:int = 0;
for each(var node:XML in xmlNodes){
var textField:TextField() = new TextField();
   addChild(textField);
   textField.y = textField.height * textFields;
textFields++;
}
```